# How can the libraries installed in python 3.6 be used in python3.7

Tags: python

I installed the following library in python 3.6 using the following command

```
pip3 install CANard
```

How can I install the same library in python 3.7 if I give

```
pip3.7 install CANard
```

it says command not found

Comment: Is that to say that `pip3.7` isn't found? If you have the necessary module installed at all but just don't have an alias for it, `python3.7 -m pip` is your friend. If you don't have pip installed for Python 3.7, then... well... you need to install it; how to do that depends on your operating system's packaging, and you haven't told us anything about which OS you're running.

Comment: it's time to use **virtual environments**. checkout [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04